# The boot buzzer produces infinite short beeps and the system never boots even though all other components appear to be working

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply, hardware-failure, beep-code

I have this old motherboard, and I was trying to revive it, which I have achieved but for a short time, since the motherboard did not have a power button, so I put 2 cables that when making contact the pc turned on (you had to separate them quickly after the first beep of the buzzer).

The problem with that is that a relative used that pc and while he was using it the cables got together and the pc turned off and on about 4 times.

After that, the PC went perfectly but when I tried again to turn on the processor, the LEDs, the hard disk, and the source, they are working perfectly but the monitor screen only goes black (it receives a signal but is stuck there) but windows never appears.
In addition, infinite start beeps begin to be heard (beep, beep, beep, beep, beep, beep, ...) until everything is turned off from the source.
At first glance I can't find anything burned on the motherboard.

At first glance I can't find anything burned on the motherboard, and all the components do receive electricity, so what could be failing?
Do you think it could be a logical error in the boot system that was left in an infinite boot loop?

I have investigated the beep code on page 27 of the official board manual, and the infinite short beeps do not appear within the beep code.

https://www.manualslib.com/manual/374121/Biostar-G41d3b.html?page=27#manual

[image]

[image]

I don't know what to do, even once, as it was emitting many beeps, I removed the buzzer because it bothered me and the system started 10 seconds after leaving the cables together, then everything was normal, but after that I couldn't get it to turn on again, just the infinite beeps and if I remove the buzzer it only remains black without starting the S.O.